# Where can I find documentation on the syntax of a "batch script"

Tags: slurm

Is the syntax (and semantics, for that matter) of "batch scripts" for `sbatch` formally documented anywhere?

(I'm looking for formal documentation, as opposed to examples.)

---

The `DESCRIPTION` section of the man page for `sbatch` begins with this paragraph:

```
   sbatch  submits a batch script to Slurm.  The batch script may be given to sbatch through a file
   name on the command line, or if no file name is specified, sbatch will read  in  a  script  from
   standard  input.  The  batch  script may contain options preceded with "#SBATCH" before any exe-
   cutable commands in the script.
```

That's about all I can find in the `sbatch` man page as to the syntax of a "batch script".

It says nothing, for example, about the fact that this script is required to begin with a shebang line.  (One may *infer* this requirement, however, from the fact that all the examples in the `EXAMPLES` section meet it.)

It also says nothing of what interpreter one should put on the command line.  Again, from the examples in the `EXAMPLES` section one may infer that `/bin/sh` is suitable, but one would have no reason to think that `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh` is also suitable (let alone, e.g., `/bin/perl` or `/bin/python` or `/bin/ruby`, etc.).

Comment: Slurm just forks and passes the script to the `exec` function on the system and this function performs all the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation indeed only specifies 'batch script', which is to be understood as '[non-interactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)'.

Only if you try to submit a compiled program are you told about the shebang:

```
$ sbatch /usr/bin/time
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first
sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh
```

But you can submit a script written in any language that supports `#` as comment symbol; the most common in that context are Bash, Python and Perl. You can also use for instance Lua but then you cannot incorporate the resource requirements in the script with `#SBATCH` directives.